# Images from previous functions are not drawn in the background (Canvas)

Tags: image, html, canvas

My question is about drawing with functions in HTML Canvas.
I try to draw "Trading Cards" with Canvas to create a Game.
So I decided to write a function that gets all necessary information to draw different cards.
For one card - no problem. But if I try to draw another card on top of the first one, the images from the first card can be seen through the second Card.

Here's the source code:

```
function RoundRect(x,y,scale,lvl,mage,headline,text,HP,MP,AtckP,DefP,MDefP){
            //Kartenumriss zeichnen
            context.strokeStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.fillStyle="rgb(180,180,180)";
            context.lineWidth=2*scale;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x+10*scale,y+0*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+90*scale,y+0*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+100*scale,y+0*scale,x+100*scale,y+10*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+100*scale,y+110*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+100*scale,y+120*scale,x+90*scale,y+120*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+10*scale,y+120*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+0*scale,y+120*scale,x+0*scale,y+110*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+0*scale,y+10*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+0*scale,y+0*scale,x+10*scale,y+0*scale,10*scale);
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();
            //innerer Kartenumriss zeichnen
            context.strokeStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.lineWidth=2*scale;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x+20*scale,y+10*scale)
            context.lineTo(x+80*scale,y+10*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+20*scale,x+90*scale,y+20*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+90*scale,y+100*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+100*scale,x+80*scale,y+110*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+20*scale,y+110*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+100*scale,x+10*scale,y+100*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+10*scale,y+20*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+20*scale,x+20*scale,y+10*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineCap="square";
            context.stroke();
            //Textfeld zeichnen
            context.strokeStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.fillStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.lineWidth=2*scale;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x+90*scale,y+65*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+90*scale,y+100*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+100*scale,x+80*scale,y+110*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+20*scale,y+110*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+100*scale,x+10*scale,y+100*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+10*scale,y+65*scale);
            context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+65*scale,x+20*scale,y+75*scale,10*scale);
            context.lineTo(x+80*scale,y+75*scale)
            context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+65*scale,x+90*scale,y+65*scale,10*scale)
            context.lineCap="square";
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();
            //lvl zeichnen
            shift=0;
            for(var greystar=0;greystar<=4; greystar++){
                context.strokeStyle="rgb(100,100,100)";
                context.fillStyle="rgb(100,100,100)";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+25.33*scale,y+118.66*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+20*scale,y+114.53*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+26.66*scale,y+114.53*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+21.26*scale,y+118.66*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
                context.fill();
                shift+=13.5*scale;
            }
            shift=0;
            while(lvl>0){
                context.strokeStyle="yellow";
                context.fillStyle="yellow";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+25.33*scale,y+118.66*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+20*scale,y+114.53*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+26.66*scale,y+114.53*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+21.26*scale,y+118.66*scale);
                context.lineTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
                context.fill();
                shift+=13.5*scale;
                lvl--;
            }
            //Bild einbinden
            var chucknorris = new Image();
            chucknorris.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(chucknorris,x+18*scale,y+18*scale,64*scale,49*scale);
            };
            chucknorris.src="pics/chucknorris.png";
            //Symbole einbinden
            //life
            var life = new Image();
            life.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(life,x+87*scale,y+11*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
            };
            life.src="pics/heart_small.png";
            //magic
            var magic = new Image();
            magic.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(magic,x+6*scale,y+11*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
            };
            magic.src="pics/magic_small.png";
            if(mage==true){
                //wand
                var wand = new Image();
                wand.onload = function() {
                    context.drawImage(wand,x+6*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
                };
                wand.src="pics/wand_small.png";
            }
            else{
                //sword
                var sword = new Image();
                sword.onload = function() {
                    context.drawImage(sword,x+6*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
                };
                sword.src="pics/sword_crossed_small.png";
            }
            //shield
            var shield = new Image();
            shield.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(shield,x+85*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
            };
            shield.src="pics/shield_small.png";
            //magic_shield
            var magic_shield = new Image();
            magic_shield.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(magic_shield,x+91*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
            };
            magic_shield.src="pics/magic_shield_small.png";
            //Text einfügen
            context.font = 'bold '+4*scale+'px Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
            context.fillText(headline,x+20*scale, y+80*scale);
            context.font = 'normal '+3*scale+'px Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
            wrapText(context, text, x+20*scale, y+85*scale, maxWidth, lineHeight, scale);
            //HP anzeigen
            context.font = 'bold 20pt Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
            var textmetric = context.measureText(HP);
            var textwidth = textmetric.width/2;
            context.fillText(HP,x-textwidth+90.25*scale, y+10*scale);
            //MP anzeigen
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
            textmetric = context.measureText(MP);
            textwidth = textmetric.width/2;
            context.fillText(MP,x-textwidth+9.5*scale, y+10*scale);
            //AtckP anzeigen
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            textmetric = context.measureText(AtckP);
            textwidth = textmetric.width/2;
            context.fillText(AtckP,x-textwidth+9.5*scale, y+115*scale);
            //DefP und MDefP anzeigen
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            var DefAll = DefP+'/'+MDefP;
            textmetric = context.measureText(DefAll);
            textwidth = textmetric.width;
            context.fillText(DefAll,x-textwidth+98*scale, y+115*scale);
        };
```

I think the important part is between "//Bild einbinden" and "//Text einfügen" but I'm not sure about that.

The function is used later in the test code like this:

```
RoundRect(0,0,4,5,false,'Chuck Norris','Wenn Chuck Norris spricht, hört Gott zu!!! Chuck Norris` Tränen können Krebs heilen. Nur schade dass er niemals weint!!! Chuck Norris geht manchmal Blut spenden. Nur nie sein eigenes. Und wenn doch, dann mit ner Knarre und nem Eimer!!!','100','0','120','20','60');
RoundRect(100,120,4,2,false,'Chuck Norris Vers 0.3','Wenn Chuck Norris spricht, hört Gott zu!!! Chuck Norris` Tränen können Krebs heilen. Nur schade dass er niemals weint!!! Chuck Norris geht manchmal Blut spenden. Nur nie sein eigenes. Und wenn doch, dann mit ner Knarre und nem Eimer!!!','50','100','60','10','30');
```

Here the result:

[Result](http://img4web.com/view/16RZTP)

I hope there's someone who can help me. Thank you in advance ever (<- hope Google-Tranlator is right here - sounds wrong for me...).

Edit:
I figured out a part of the problem, but I still need a solution:
I tried to set some "alert();"s in the code. The result was interessting: First, the background from the first card is drawed. Then the background of the second card. After that the images of the first card are drawed, then the others from the second card. So the images where drawn AFTER everything else is drawn.
So the Problem is how to tell the the Canvas to draw the images immediately, or at least within the function.

Answer (score 1):

You get the images drawn after everything because they are drawn in the callback of Image.onLoad().

This means that the function will first render the background of the first card, register a listener for your Image.onLoad events, then return, so that you can make the seconde call, which will render the background, and register another listener for the new Image.onLoad events. Then the first listener is triggered when the first image is loaded, so it will draw the picture, and a last the second listener will be triggered. Hence your result.

As for a way to resolve this issue, either you can load your images before drawing any card, and draw it directly in your function, avoiding to wait for the loading, or you hav to make your design Asynchronous-proof. You can get information about asynchronous programming here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/?redirect_from_locale=why

Edit: The second solution can help with the first one (which corresponds to the answer of enzhflep). The article recommands the use of jquery to deal with asynchronous events such as loading multiple images. But if you don't need jQuery, you can also code a small javascript object that can register images to be loaded, and trigger a listener when all images are loaded. [This ressource](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column3/index.html) seems to offer that specific object.

Comment: Thank you, too. I'll read this article at any rate. But I'd like to test enhzflep's solution first.^^

Answer (score 0):

Is not a problem. Your english is fine. (the translation you mention is a little odd 'thank-you in advance)

As you appear to be starting to identify, the problem is due to the time it takes to load images..

Each time you draw a card, you load each of it's images. Once each image is loaded, it's onload handler fires and draws it to the canvas. Now, the problem is that sometimes the images from the first card are still loading when you draw the second card. This means that parts of the second card have been drawn before card 1's images have loaded. When they finally do load, they are drawn on top of card2.

You an get around this by loading the images in your page's init function.

Here's a solution I used:

```
var canvas, context;

var chucknorris = new Image();
var life = new Image();
var magic = new Image();
var wand = new Image();
var sword = new Image();
var shield = new Image();
var magic_shield = new Image();

function myInit()
{
    chucknorris.src="img/girl.png"; //"pics/chucknorris.png";
    life.src="img/heartSmall.jpg"; //"pics/heart_small.png";
    magic.src="img/magicSmall.jpg"; //"pics/magic_small.png";
    wand.src="img/magicSmall.jpg"; //"pics/wand_small.png";
    sword.src="img/magicSmall.jpg"; //"pics/sword_crossed_small.png";
    shield.src="img/close.png"; //pics/shield_small.png";
    magic_shield.src="img/magicSmall.jpg"; //"pics/magic_shield_small.png";

    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '400');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '800');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    RoundRect(0,0,2,5,false,'Chuck Norris','Wenn Chuck Norris spricht, hört Gott zu!!! Chuck Norris` Tränen können Krebs heilen. Nur schade dass er niemals weint!!! Chuck Norris geht manchmal Blut spenden. Nur nie sein eigenes. Und wenn doch, dann mit ner Knarre und nem Eimer!!!','100','0','120','20','60');

    RoundRect(128,0,2,5,false,'Pussy Galore','She loves Austin Powers','100','0','120','20','60');
}



function RoundRect(x,y,scale,lvl,mage,headline,text,HP,MP,AtckP,DefP,MDefP)
{
    var mImages

    //Kartenumriss zeichnen
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "src-over";

    context.strokeStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.fillStyle="rgb(180,180,180)";
    context.lineWidth=2*scale;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x+10*scale,y+0*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+90*scale,y+0*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+100*scale,y+0*scale,x+100*scale,y+10*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+100*scale,y+110*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+100*scale,y+120*scale,x+90*scale,y+120*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+10*scale,y+120*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+0*scale,y+120*scale,x+0*scale,y+110*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+0*scale,y+10*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+0*scale,y+0*scale,x+10*scale,y+0*scale,10*scale);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    //innerer Kartenumriss zeichnen
    context.strokeStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.lineWidth=2*scale;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x+20*scale,y+10*scale)
    context.lineTo(x+80*scale,y+10*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+20*scale,x+90*scale,y+20*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+90*scale,y+100*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+100*scale,x+80*scale,y+110*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+20*scale,y+110*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+100*scale,x+10*scale,y+100*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+10*scale,y+20*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+20*scale,x+20*scale,y+10*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineCap="square";
    context.stroke();
    //Textfeld zeichnen
    context.strokeStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.fillStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.lineWidth=2*scale;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x+90*scale,y+65*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+90*scale,y+100*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+100*scale,x+80*scale,y+110*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+20*scale,y+110*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+100*scale,x+10*scale,y+100*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+10*scale,y+65*scale);
    context.arcTo(x+20*scale,y+65*scale,x+20*scale,y+75*scale,10*scale);
    context.lineTo(x+80*scale,y+75*scale)
    context.arcTo(x+80*scale,y+65*scale,x+90*scale,y+65*scale,10*scale)
    context.lineCap="square";
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    //lvl zeichnen
    shift=0;
    for(var greystar=0;greystar<=4; greystar++)
    {
        context.strokeStyle="rgb(100,100,100)";
        context.fillStyle="rgb(100,100,100)";
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+25.33*scale,y+118.66*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+20*scale,y+114.53*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+26.66*scale,y+114.53*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+21.26*scale,y+118.66*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
        context.fill();
        shift+=13.5*scale;
    }
    shift=0;
    while(lvl>0)
    {
        context.strokeStyle="yellow";
        context.fillStyle="yellow";
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+25.33*scale,y+118.66*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+20*scale,y+114.53*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+26.66*scale,y+114.53*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+21.26*scale,y+118.66*scale);
        context.lineTo(shift+x+23.33*scale,y+112*scale);
        context.fill();
        shift+=13.5*scale;
        lvl--;
    }
    //Bild einbinden
    context.drawImage(chucknorris,x+18*scale,y+18*scale,64*scale,49*scale);

    //Symbole einbinden
    //life
    context.drawImage(life,x+87*scale,y+11*scale,7*scale,7*scale);

    //magic
        context.drawImage(magic,x+6*scale,y+11*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
    if(mage==true)
    {
        context.drawImage(wand,x+6*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
    }
    else{
            context.drawImage(sword,x+6*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
    }
    //shield
        context.drawImage(shield,x+85*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);

        //magic_shield
//  magic_shield.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(magic_shield,x+91*scale,y+102*scale,7*scale,7*scale);
//  };

    //Text einfügen
    context.font = 'bold '+4*scale+'px Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
    context.fillText(headline,x+20*scale, y+80*scale);
    context.font = 'normal '+3*scale+'px Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
    wrapText(context, text, x+20*scale, y+85*scale, maxWidth, lineHeight, scale);
    //HP anzeigen
    context.font = 'bold 20pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
    var textmetric = context.measureText(HP);
    var textwidth = textmetric.width/2;
    context.fillText(HP,x-textwidth+90.25*scale, y+10*scale);
    //MP anzeigen
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
    textmetric = context.measureText(MP);
    textwidth = textmetric.width/2;
    context.fillText(MP,x-textwidth+9.5*scale, y+10*scale);
    //AtckP anzeigen
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    textmetric = context.measureText(AtckP);
    textwidth = textmetric.width/2;
    context.fillText(AtckP,x-textwidth+9.5*scale, y+115*scale);
    //DefP und MDefP anzeigen
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    var DefAll = DefP+'/'+MDefP;
    textmetric = context.measureText(DefAll);
    textwidth = textmetric.width;
    context.fillText(DefAll,x-textwidth+98*scale, y+115*scale);
};
```

Comment: That should work if your connection is fast enough to load the images before they are needed to be drawn. Maybe you should check that all images are loaded before calling RoundRect.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this, and post the result later. @TonioElGringo: How would you check this?

Comment: @TonioElGringo - That's a good point. Thanks for providing the clarity I neglected to! Loading resources from localhost is always gonna be quicker than across a wire or air :)

Comment: @Sandro I edited my answer with a link to an article on how to load multiple images, and call a function when all images are loaded.

Comment: Thanks again. Should work. At least I hope so. I'll post the result later.

Comment: I've tested the code now. It does not work, but I think the problem is not the Idea behind but how to put it into my own code. But I think thats the smaller Problem. So thank you for your Answers.

Comment: My pleasure Sandro. Here, try this - it works just fine here - my internet is quite slow. I hope it will work for your too. http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/RLP5Y/ or this one: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/RLP5Y/1/ (extra unrelated code in the first)